# Rails 3: Problem with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a problem I can not resolve on a form

Here's my view:

> ```
> <h1>create manager </h1>
> <% form_tag :action => 'create_manager' do %>
>
>     <%= text_area :user, :nom %><br/>
>     <%= date_select :user, :date_embauche %>
>     <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
>
> <% end %>
> ```

and here is my controller:

```
  def create_manager
    tmp = params[:user][:date_embauche]
    p(tmp)
    tmp1 = params[:user][:nom]
    p(tmp1)
    render :partial => "adminpartial"
  end
```

The problème is that **params[:user][:nom]** returns a correct result but **params[:user][:date_embauche]** returns alltime **nil**.

I think i'm not using correctly the **params** variable.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

**UPDATE**

Thank you both for your help.
I do not know why I have not directly had the idea to go see the log'-__-

The answer is:

```
tmp = params["user"]["date_embauche(1i)"]
```

with:
    date_embauche(1i)
    date_embauche(2i)
    ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is quite strange `date_select` helper behavior

```
day   = params[:user][:date_embauche_day]
month = params[:user][:date_embauche_month]
year  = params[:user][:date_embauche_year]
# and hour, min, seconds
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I've tried your solution but params[:user][:date_embauche_day] give me alltime nil too :/

Comment: @Michaël you need to go into your HTML sources and look into this select tag (and you can show the to me as well) - there you can see what are the names of particular elements.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the Rails console on how the data is posted to the server. By inspecting that hashmap you will be able to get an idea.